# formatting issue in printf script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file ***stv.txt*** containing some names
For example ***stv.txt*** is as follows:

```
hello  
world
```

I want to generate another file by using these names and adding some extra   text to them.I have written a script as follows

```
for i in `cat stvv.txt`; 
do printf 'if(!strcmp("$i",optarg))' > my_file; 
done
```

### output

```
if(!strcmp("$i",optarg))
```

### desired output

```
if(!strcmp("hello",optarg))  
if(!strcmp("world",optarg))
```

how can I get the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution.

> 1  All symbols inside single quotes is considered a string. 
>  2 When using printf, do not surround the variable with quotes. (in this example) 
>   
>   The code below should fix it,

```
for i in `cat stvv.txt`; 
   printf 'if(!strcmp('$i',optarg))' > my_file; 
done
```

basically, break the printf statement into three parts.

> 1: the string 'if(!strcmp('
>   2: $i (no quotes)
>   3: the string ',optarg))'

hope that helps!

Comment: You forgot the double quotes around $i.

Comment: No, I didn't. You need quotes around $i when you're using echo statements. No need for printf

Answer (score 0):

To insert a string into a `printf` format, use `%s` in the format string:

```
$ for line in $(cat stvv.txt); do printf 'if(!strcmp("%s",optarg))\n' "$line"; done
if(!strcmp("hello",optarg))
if(!strcmp("world",optarg))
```

The code `$(cat stvv.txt)` will perform word splitting and pathname expansion on the contents of `stvv.txt`.  You probably don't want that.  It is generally safer to use a `while read ... done <stvv.txt` loop such as this one:

```
$ while read -r line; do printf 'if(!strcmp("%s",optarg))\n' "$line"; done <stvv.txt
if(!strcmp("hello",optarg))
if(!strcmp("world",optarg))
```

#### Aside on `cat`

If you are using `bash`, then `$(cat stvv.txt)` could be replaced with the more efficient `$(<stvv.txt)`.  This question, however, is tagged `shell` not `bash`.  The `cat` form is POSIX and therefore portable to all POSIX shells while the bash form is not.